# How to create a user foo and adjust the admintrator rights of foo?

Tags: 12.04

I was trying to install skype with a different user foo I got this error message, can someone help?

```
asudipta@asudipta-Inspiron-1525:~$ sudo -u foo -H skype
sudo: unknown user: foo
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Can some help me with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `id foo` say?

Comment: @Steeldriver I dont think you got my point. I am trying to create another user with secondary access. I am asking about the process